# Is it polite or annoying to send a professor a short "Thanks" email?

Tags: etiquette, email

After asking a professor a question through e-mail and receiving an answer, is it polite that a student send a short e-mail simply saying "Thanks" as an acknowledgment that the answer was received and appreciated? I'm thinking of sending this but am not sure if it might be considered annoying or unnecessary  (as I'm not sure how busy the professor is, or how many emails he/she has to sort through every day.)

Is there some widely agreed-upon etiquette for this?

Comment: You're over-thinking it, just express your gratitude that is appropriate with the professor's effort and move on. General practice in the US is if you've to make a choice, lean towards the more formal one. However, I have yet heard of any colleague complaining to me about someone never sent thank you e-mail nor someone always sent thank you e-mail.